# Something blocks my memory and the program hangs on GC.Collect() or GC.GetTotalAmountOfMemory(true)

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, block

<strike>whenever I call a `GC.Collect()` or `GC.GetTotalAmountOfMemory(true)` the whole program just hangs. Now, I know what you gonna say: Don't call `GC.Collect()` the GC takes care of itself. The problem is: It doesn't in my case, something hangs around in memory and the GC can't get rid of it.</strike>

I've no idea what it could be (project is big/old). I hope someone knows how to obtain informations about what the GC tries to do (and obviously can't do) so that I can search for the problem or if something like a memory profiler could be of any help here (I've ANTS currently installed) and what I should search for.

*edit 
something I totally forgot: Sometimes when I call one of the two methods of GC, the memory usage increases by ~10 kilobytes / second

*edit2
I've to correct myself: GC.Collect() runs just fine. Only GC.GetTotalMemory(true) hangs. GC.GetTotalMemory(false) works just fine, too.

*edit3
and yup as some of you already said: It seems to be a finalizer somewhere. When I run WaitForPendingFinalizers() it just sits there, doing nothing aswell.

ok, now I'm completely confused: When I enter a `GC.GetTotalMemor(true)` or a `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` into the immediate window of Visual Studio after I paused the debugger, the program hangs (*that's what I did the whole time...I feel stupid now*). When I add it to my usual source code and compile it, it works just fine.

Sorry about the whole fuzz, seems the memoryleak has another cause.

Comment: If you have a memory leak, calling `GC.Collect()` won't help

Comment: GC.Collect() or GetTotalAmountOfMemory() can only hang if the heap is corrupted.  Look for bad pinvoke or COM code.

Comment: Is it hanging, or simply taking a long time?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear about it: The memory leak occurs because the GC is not able to collect something that should be collected, that way all other objects that are created while working in a specific part of the program don't get collected aswell, and that is the memory leak. At thecoop: Good question, I let it run for half an hour and it just does nothing (no processor using, no memory change except for some rare occasions...see edit of main post).

Comment: Search for `unsafe` and look for code that writes to managed memory, sounds like a corrupted heap.

Comment: Something is hanging in a broken destructor. Try to debug it. Call GC.Collect() and then try to break in.

Comment: Attach a debugger and see where the program is hanging. It might be a deadlock in a finalizer or (more likely since you mention increasing memory use) an infinite loop in a finalizer.

Comment: Ever thought of finding the bug? there are memoryp rofilers out there that can you help analyze the memory and change over time.

Comment: GC.GetTotalMemory(true) in immediate window **will** make the app hang, I think it happens because the debugger paused all threads (and GC) while GetTotalMemory is waiting for something to complete in another thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you override any finalizers? When a finalizer is not returning ( Maybe you are waiting at any point for another thread ) the application may hang. The `GC.Collect()` invokes the finalizer but its never returning since it waits for a finalizer to return. This may be also the cause for your memory leak because the GC cannot finish the garbage collection.

#### Solution

You should be able to debug it, when the GC is collecting and you press "pause" it should show you the stack trace where it hangs. If everything goes wrong you maybe need to check the disassembly where your application is hanging.

#### GetTotalMemory(true)

This method forces the garbage collection, so it's the same like `GC.Collect()`.

#### Update

Lets take a look at GetTotalMemory:

```
public static long GetTotalMemory(bool forceFullCollection)
{
    long totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory();
    if (!forceFullCollection)
    {
        return totalMemory;
    }
    int remainingSteps = 20;
    long lastMemory = totalMemory;
    float num4;
    do
    {
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        totalMemory = lastMemory;
        lastMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory();
        num4 = (float)(lastMemory - totalMemory) / (float)totalMemory;
    }
    while (remainingSteps-- > 0 && (-0.05 >= (double)num4 || (double)num4 >= 0.05));
    
    return lastMemory;
}
```

As you can see that `GetTotalMemory` is waiting for finalizers, so it has to be a finalizer which hangs up the application. `GC.Collect()` is called when the finalizers are finished and will never be called because it never passes the line before.

At any point in your application ( unsafe code? another thread? ) there is something which allocates a lot of memory while the GC never has the chance to clean up existing memory.

#### Disclaimer

This is a pure guess, i don't know if the GC handles such situations but i think it cannot break the execution of a finalizer because it may take a long time and the GC doesn't know if he is just hanging or still finalizing.

Comment: there has to be a difference because GC.Collect() actually works, while GetTotalMemory(true) blocks the whole thing. I assumed the same, that's why I didn't check it earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered to use the server mode GC settings, so that one GC thread runs per processor core?
Have you investigated the issue using performance counters, dumps or profilers? ANTS Memory profiler is very helpful if the application itself does not get slowed too much by the use of it.
I would also look at your application using Windows Process Explorer to get a taste what is happening on the memory side.

Comment: those are a lot of things (GC server mode, performance counters) that I've to search for thanks :). Also thanks to you, I found out that the ProcessExplorer (which I'm using for a few months now) has the ability to display GPU performance and the threads that are running in a program

Comment: Forgot to mention that the other hard way would be to generate and analyze dumps, but reading dumps is an art on its own.

Comment: Regarding dumps, I've made the painful experience that they won't work as long as the application is inside an active garbage collection.